# External Javascript doesn't load in VSCode

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I'm working in VSCODE. I have an html page and I want to include an external javascript file in it.

this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Javascript Exercise</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
       
   </head>

   <body onload="addTable()">
       <div class="title">Reports</div>        

       <!-- singolo run test -->
       <div class="block">
           <h1> Ultimo test eseguito </h1>

           <div id="myDynamicTableTitles" class="table"></div>
           <div id="myDynamicTable" class="table"></div>
           
       </div>

       <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
       <script src="./index.js"></script> 

   </body>

   


</html>
```

I know for sure that the js I wrote works, because if I put the js directly inside the  `<script></script>`  the page works.

Any idea on why, if I put it into an external file, it doesn't load? I'm also sure that the path  `"./index.js"`  it's correct.

I've noticed that if I click directly on the file html it works (like from the computer explorer). But if I load the project trough VSCode, it doesn't.

when I execute `npm start` it compile and gives me an `http://localhost:xxxx`

Comment: Your code looks fine. You forgot a closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: put all code in your `<body onload="addTable()"> code </body>`

Comment: put all code into body & closed the body properly. still doesn't work :(

Comment: You just click on .html file, right? or do you have this on a server?

Comment: modify your question to fix the `body` tag and let us know if you still have a problem with the update code

Comment: Either (a) `./index.js` doesn't point to your JS file (the Network tab if the browser's developer tools should tell you this) or (b) You made an error when transcribing it (in which case you should see an error in the Console tab of the browser's developer tools).

Comment: I've noticed that if I click directly on the file html it works (like from the computer explorer). But if I load the project trough VSCode, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To make an example...
Maybe the script have an error?

```js
function addTable(table) {
 //Maybe you miss something? Here's an example 
 // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // creates a table row
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
      // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
      // the end of the table row
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell in row "+i+", column "+j);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Javascript Exercise</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
       
   </head>

   <body onload="addTable()"></body>

   <div class="title">Reports</div>        

       <!-- singolo run test -->
       <div class="block">
           <h1> Ultimo test eseguito </h1>

           <div id="myDynamicTableTitles" class="table"></div>
           <div id="myDynamicTable" class="table"></div>
           
       </div>

   <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
   <script src="./index.js"></script> 

   <!-- add this -->
   </body> 
</html>
```

You can find more explanations of this JScode in [this great page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces)
Divertiti

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed that if I click directly on the file html it works (like from the computer explorer). But if I load the project trough VSCode, it doesn't.

It sounds like you are using the [Live HTML Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer) extension which says:

> Note: Javascript is not supported in preview

Use a browser to test your browser-dependant JS.

Comment: I'm not using that extension. when I execute `npm start` it compile and gives me an `http://localhost:xxxx`

Comment: Err. So are you saying that you get the problem when you load `http://localhost:xxxx/` but not file you load `file:///path/to/your/index.html`? If so then the problem is almost certainly with the server side JS you didn't show us which is responsible for running your HTTP server.